# Share authentication from parent window with embedded iframe window

Tags: reactjs, authentication, iframe

##### Applications

Say I have two applications, both hosted on different domains (`www.parent.com` and `www.iframe.com`).

The first application is displayed in a normal browser window, and the second is displayed in an embedded iFrame *within* that other application.

##### The Problem

Both applications need access tokens to get data from our API, and what I would like is a way that once a user has authenticated and been granted an access token in the first app, for that token to be shared with the second app.

This ensures that users who have authenticated in the first app do not have to re-authenticate themselves in the embedded iframe application.

##### Solutions?

One (likely impractical) solution that I have come across for sharing authentication is in embedding the access token within the url hash of the `iframe` `src` attribute. From here, we could set up our frontend to pull this token and use it to authenticate requests sent to our API. The only problem with this is that it does not appear very secure.

```
www.iframe.com/redirect#<my-token-here>
```

For additional context, this project has a React frontend and a Ruby backend (as the API).